# VB.NET Forms ListBox doesn't display DataSource

Tags: vb.net, listbox

I'm trying to link my ListBox to an ObservableCollection.
Here's my class for defining mods:

```
Public Class TroveMod
    Private m_FileName As String
    Private m_Enabled As Boolean
    Public Property FileName() As String
        Get
            Return m_FileName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_FileName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Enabled() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_Enabled
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            m_Enabled = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ModName()
        Get
            Return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileName)
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

And this is the actual Property ModList:

```
Public Property ModList() As ObservableCollection(Of TroveMod)
    Get
        Return m_ModList
    End Get
    Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of TroveMod))
        m_ModList = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I add items using:

```
Private Sub AddMod(file__1 As String, enabled As Boolean)
    If File.Exists(file__1) Then
        ModList.Add(New TroveMod() With { _
             .FileName = file__1, _
             .Enabled = enabled _
        })
    End If
End Sub
```

Everytime I want to add something to this Collection using AddMod, it won't show off in my listbox :/ I added an ModListBindingSource to the ListBox and set the DisplayMember and ValueMember to ModName but it still won't work. I also got a status label, which says, that it successful added the mods to the collection but it simply won't show them in the ListBox. Did I miss something?

Comment: As far as it goes what you have looks good - where is the code binding the collection to the ListBox?  Also where is the `ModList` property located - on what class?  I am not sure you really want/need a setter there.

Comment: The ModList property is located in the Form class, which I made partitial.and actually there is no code for binding. I just set the DataSource in the designer and thought that would work...do I still need a binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ObservableCollection` is not quite what you want - this would allow your code to see changes to the collection via events.  For instance, if there were several actors adding items to the collection and you wanted to know that.  In this case, since 'local' code is adding items, it is not needed.

It is also not clear how the collection is mapped to the `ListBox` as the `DataSource`.  Try this:

```
Public Class Form...
    Private myList As New BindingList(Of TroveMod)

    Sub Form_Load(....
        theListBox.DataSource = myList
        theListBox.DisplayMember = "ModName"
```

Now, as you add things to the `BindingList` they will appear in `theListBox`.  If an item *changes* though (e.g. the Name), that change will not show up without a little more work, but as these are file names that seems unlikely.

The form property is not needed unless an external class also needs access to the collection/`BindingList`; in that case, you probably do not want need a setter.